# How do I copy a directory from one location to another using Ant?

Tags: ant

I am looking to copy a directory from one location to another.  However, after looking at "copy" and "copyDir" (which is deprecated) it seems that Ant, by default, only copies the content of one location to another, not the actual directory (and everything in it).

So, as an example I have the following:

```
./Foo/test.txt
```

And I apply the following piece of Ant:

```
 <copy todir="./build">
    <fileset dir="./Foo"/>
 </copy>
```

The result looks like this:

```
./build/test.txt
```

Whereas I would like it to be:

```
./build/Foo/test.txt
```

Hope that makes sense.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the structure you would need to be copying the parent folder. There is a flatten option in the copy command, but it defaults to false. You can also make the directory structure you want, then copy at the file level straight into your fresh folder.

Here is the relevant line from the [reference](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/copy.html):

> When a <fileset> is used to select files to copy,
>       the todir attribute must be set. Files that are 
>       located under the base directory of the <fileset> 
>       will be copied to a directory under the destination 
>       directory matching the path relative to the base 
>       directory of the <fileset>, unless the flatten
>   attribute is set to true.

The problem lies in that you are picking up the Foo folder, so you only get the files **under** it, you need to pick the folder above Foo to get the fileset where the ~/Foo/file.txt structure exists.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
<copy todir="./build">
  <fileset dir=".">
    <include name="Foo/**"/> 
  </fileset>
</copy>
```